# Parsing CSV file with @Parsed annotation in a Form - Univocity parser

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I am trying to parse a CSV file with some `@Parsed` annotation in a form file but it's not working.

I am using `univocity` lib

> Init.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

        BeanListProcessor<FireReportFormGeneral> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<FireReportFormGeneral>(FireReportFormGeneral.class);

        parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
        parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);


        parser.parse(new FileReader("/home/jose/Desktop/example.csv"));
        List<FireReportFormGeneral> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
        System.out.println(rowProcessor.getHeaders());
        System.out.println(beans);

    }
```

> FireReportFormGeneral.java

```
@Parsed(field = "Account Number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Parsed(field = "Account Type")
    private String accountType;

    @Parsed(field = "Bank Client Identification Number")
    private String bankClientIdNumber;

    @Parsed(field = "Account Opening Date")
    private String accountOpeningDate;

    //getters and setters
```

But my output is always something like:

> [Ljava.lang.String;@7591083d
>   [com.opessoftware.fire.csv.reader.FireReportFormGeneral@77a567e1,
>   com.opessoftware.fire.csv.reader.FireReportFormGeneral@736e9adb]

For sure I am doing something wrong but I could not find the answer.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I solve the problem

The thing is if a call `beans.get(index).getAccountName()` for example it's going to return values for me.

Comment: What is tour parser? `univocity-parsers`? If that's so, retag the post.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh I can not tag univocity, I already tried :/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a toString() method to FireReportFormGeneral.java, then your System.out.println() should be more readable.

eg.

```
public String toString(){
return "Account number: " + accountNumber + " Account Type: " + accountType;
}
```

This is just a simple example, without null checks, StringBuilder etc...

Does this solve your problem?